# Uniqueness in Baire property representation for compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space.

I know that every Borel set $B$ is congruent to a **regular closed** set $R$ modulo a meager set $M$. In other words, $B\oplus R=M$ (where $\oplus$ denotes the operation of symmetric difference).

I would like to show that this decomposition is **unique** in the sense that there exists a unique $R$ such that $B\oplus R=M$. I know this involves the Baire category theorem. How does the argument unfold?

Comment: Perhaps you can utilize the 150 characters limit of a title and give the question a better title. Perhaps something that reflects the content of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $G \oplus P = H \oplus Q$ where $G,H$ are regular open, then check that
$H \setminus \overline{G} \subseteq H \oplus G = P \oplus Q$ and so $H \setminus \overline{G}$ is an open set which is meagre, so empty ($X$ is a Baire space), so $H \subseteq \overline{G}$, so $H \subseteq G$ as both sets are regular open. By symmetry $G = H$ and we have unicity.

Comment: How does this translate if we have regular closed sets instead or regular open sets?

Comment: Replace a regular closed set by its interior. The difference is meagre. The interior is regular open.@student

Comment: @student Or use that if $A = F \oplus M$, $F$ regular closed, $M$ meagre, we can also write $X\setminus A = (X\setminus F) \oplus M$ and so the complement has a (unique) representation via a regular open set (namely $X\setminus F$). And vice versa. So if via regular open is unique so is via regular closed.